# $K_X \oplus K_Y=\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}) \iff Y=\mathbb{R} - X$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that

$K_X \oplus K_Y=\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}) \iff Y=\mathbb{R} - X$

Where:

$K_X = \{ \phi \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}) \mid \phi(x)=0 ,\forall x \in X \}$.

$\mathbb{R}-X $ is the set of the elements that are in $\mathbb{R}$ and are not in $X$.

$\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ is the set of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$

Let $f \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}) $. Then $f$ can be uniquely decomposed in the sum $f=g+h$, where $g \in K_X$ and $h \in K_Y$.

Then $h=f-g \in K_Y \Rightarrow (f-g)(x)=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=g(x), \forall x \in Y$.  How can I conclude then that $Y=\mathbb{R}-X$?

$(\Leftarrow)$

Suppose $Y=\mathbb{R}-X$.

I can see that $K_Y \cap K_X=\{0\}$, since a function 
defined on $Y$ is not defined on $X$. But why would a sum of two such functions be a function in $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb R-X$? What is $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$

Comment: There are some typos/mistakes (e.g $\ker(X)\cap \ker(Y)=\emptyset$). 
Looking at the decomposition of the constant function $1$, might not be a bad idea.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}-X $ is the set of the elements that are in $\mathbb{R}$ and are not in $X$. $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ is the set of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\Bbb R - X$ is not a vector space

Comment: You should change the name of your operators/set, as they're sometimes redundant. You have $X$ and $Y$ two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $K_X$ (resp. $K_Y$) a subvector spaces of the real functions on $\mathbb{R}$ which consist of the function that vanish on $X$ (resp. Y).
You want to prove that $K_X\oplus K_Y=F(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ iff $\mathbb{R}=X\cup Y$ and $X\cap Y=\emptyset$

Comment: Alternatively, you could define $\hat X: F(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})\to \prod_{x\in X}\mathbb{R}$ that maps $f$ to $(f(x))_{x\in X}$ and $\hat Y$ similarly, then $K_X=\ker \hat X$. But simply calling it $\ker(X)$ is... confusing.

Comment: Now you can simply use my earlier hint: look at the decomposition of the constant function 1.

Comment: @A.Rod,  
I tried, but was not capable of decompose 1 in two functions that are in $K_X$ and $K_Y$... can you please show me the decomposition?

Comment: $1 = 1_X + 1_Y$ when $Y = \Bbb R - X$,  where $1_S$ is the characteristic function of any set $S$: $$1_S(t) = \begin{cases}1& t\in S\\0 & t\notin S\end{cases}$$

Comment: In your final statement, you have it wrong: The functions in $K_X$ are defined on all of $\Bbb R$, and the functions in $K_Y$ are defined on all of $\Bbb R$. $K_X \cap K_Y = \{0\}$ because if $f \in K_X \cap K_Y$, then $f(t) = 0$ for all $t\in X$ and $f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in Y$, but those include every element of $\Bbb R$, so $f(t) = 0$ everywhere.